# Laravel multiple named optional parameters where order don't matter

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes

I'm trying to achieve the following routing in Laravel

```
/stats/{id}
/stats/{id}/limit/{limit}
/stats/{id}/limit/{limit}/order/{order}
/stats/{id}/order/{order}
/stats/{id}/order/{order}/limit/{limit}
```

As you can see, only {id} is required, /limit/ and /order/ may or may not appear and their order shouldn't matter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but I think that the best approach to this is to send `limit` and `order` as query params instead of creating route options for them. Like:

`/stats/{id}?order={order}&limit={limit}`

This way you can add as many optional params as you want.

Comment: I thought there would be a prettier solution, but this works!

Answer (score 0):

Use `?` a question mark after parameter. Like:

```
/stats/{id}/order/{order?}/limit/{limit?}
```

Source: [Laravel Route Optional Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks a lot. that was a typo. Edited.